# Ansible - Retry task until a file contains a log line

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have an executable, lets say */tmp/foo*

I want to try to run (5 times at most) this binary file until I see a line in a log file: lets say */tmp/start.log*

I need such kind of a play:

```
- block:
    - shell: /tmp/foo

    - pause: seconds=30

    - name: Check if started successfully
      shell: grep 'started successfully' /tmp/start.log
      register: grep
  retry: 5
  until: grep.stdout
```

But unfortunately Ansible block does not support **retry-until**.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why not combine the three commands in a single shell script?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd shot with single command:

```
- shell: /tmp/foo; sleep 30; grep 'started successfully' /tmp/start.log
  register: cmd_result
  retries: 5
  until: cmd_result | success
```

Answer (score 3):

For this case using a plain shell script should be the easiest method.

Shell script `start_foo.sh` (depending on the `/tmp/foo` exit code you might control if and where the script should fail with `set -e` and `set +e`):

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e    # fail the script if the command fails
/tmp/foo
sleep 30
set +e    # do not fail the script when string is not found
grep 'started successfully' /tmp/start.log
exit 0
```

Ansible task:

```
- script: start_foo.sh
  register: grep
  retry: 5
  until: grep.stdout
```